# Get Libreoffice Writer to restablish links with JabRef when I reopen the .docx file?

Tags: citations, libreoffice-writer

I'm using Libreoffice Writer V 5.1.6.2 on Ubuntu Linux (16.04) and managed to get it to connect to Jabref, such that I can insert citations in line in the text, and it generates the References section at the bottom of the document quite nicely.  The problem arises when I quit for the day and return later.  If I close both Writer and JabRef, and then restart Writer, open the previously saved .docx file, then open JabRef and make the manual connection from Jabref, it looses the connections to the previous citations.  The previous ones are there, but in text format only, so If I add new citation, it begins again at Reference 1  as in [1].  My question is, is there a way to save the docx file such that when I reopen it, it will again establish connection with JabRef so I can continue citing from where I left off, eg. if I've already added 5 citations in the previous session, it will add a new one at [6]?

Thanks, J.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong file type.  From http://help.jabref.org/en/OpenOfficeIntegration:

> Make sure to save your Writer document in OpenDocument format (odt). Saving to Word format will lose your reference marks.